# Java Application don't close after running my Code

Tags: java, hibernate

i am trying `Hibernate 4` in `Netbeans 8`, the problem is that after the the committed is done the application still running.

Here is the code

```
public class TestHibernateAnotation {


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

Users user = new Users();
 Users user2 = new Users();

user2.setUser_name("Djalil");
user.setUser_name("Daniel");

Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
session.save(user);
session.save(user2);
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
System.out.print("End of code");

}
}
```

My Hibernate Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate      Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-   configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/SalesTest</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
<mapping class="testhibernateanotation.NewClass"/>
<mapping class="testhibernateanotation.Users"/>
```

any Idea about this issue 
thank you,

Comment: Reconsider how you name your objects and methods. The class `Users` represents a single use, so `User` would be a better name. The user has a property `name` so `setName` would be the setter method. In any case `setUser_name` is bad java naming and not according the conventions. This should be at least `setUserName`

Comment: no way!! so u r saying that infinite entries has been done in you table?

Comment: No i am just saying the the in Netbeans you see the application as running

Comment: @MichaëlBenjaminSaerens that class is probably autogenerated from the table "Users".

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly destroy the service registry after `session.close();`. This seems to be a bug in newer hibernate versions. So basically your code that cleans up at the end should look like :

```
sessionFactory.close();
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(sessionFactory.getSessionFactoryOptions().getServiceRegistry());
```

Plug: I had posted an example [here](https://ranjithchandran.wordpress.com/2015/05/06/hibernate-4-3-maven-mysql-old-fashion-example/) - including this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution (in an other post),
it would be adding this to your config files:

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">10</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">100</property>
```

They said that it is bug in `hibernate 4`

Answer (score 1):

you will have to close the SessionFactory object [ HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession() ]

The SessionFactory is a heavyweight object; it is usually created during application start up and kept for later use.The SessionFactory is a thread safe object and used by all the threads of an application.
We can create one SessionFactory implementation per database in any application. If your application is referring to multiple databases, then you need to create one SessionFactory per database.

its how hibernate SessionFactory was designed.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html